# payment gateway with ccavenue in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi I want to integrate ccavenue payment gateway in my website but how to start with that i have no idea. I had finish the page with where user will Enter his billing and Shipping address but what will be next thing to fire Please Help me

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to subscribe for this service with CCAvenue and they will provide you the document with all the details regarding how to integrate and implement their service..

You will find details in that document(pdf), like you have to set particular values into particular hidden input elements and set the form action to some particular URL and API to use for data encryption etc

Comment: Hey hi thnz 4 comment yea it has been subscribe i have merchant id an all i got 1 Ccavennue Integration  Manual  PDF

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you each and every steps to integrate CC Avenue Payment gateway.

**Requirement**
You need a live or staging website, in which you would like to integrate CC Avenue payment gateway.

**Step 1**
Register your website as Individual or company. Here you want provide URL address of your website.

**Step 2**
They (CC Avenue) will review your website and most probably one representative will call you and understand about your website.

**Step 3**
They will give you some suggestions for your website if any.
*Note :* They want to study about their risk, if they grand you their payment gateway. They mainly verify your **About, Privacy, Terms & Conditions and Contact Us** pages.

**Step 4**
Next step is that, they will make decision that **Approve** or **Reject** your request.

**Step 5**
If they approve, they will give you user id and password to log in **Merchant** account. From this step you can start integrate CC Avenue payment gateway. I am not specify how to integrate CC Avenue payment gateway in your website here. I think it is not in this scope.

**Step 6**
Still your account is not active. You need to send some required documents to their office. Some documents are sent via email and other some are via courier.

**Step 7**
By verify your documents they will approve your account. That's all !!!

Now your customers can pay cash to your account.